# PHP - dynamically assign values to key in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two array values:

```
$values = ["Phillip", "Phil"];
```

In my `set()` method, I want to return an array object that first has a defined name key and second nickname key, like:

```
array(2) {
  "name" => "Phillip"
  "nickname" => "Phil"
}
```

Is there a better way to do it? I am new at PHP, though.

```
function set(?array $values)
{
    $items = [];
    foreach ($values as &$item) {
        $item['name']     = $items;
        $item['nickname'] = $items;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you determine which is the name and nickname?

Comment: `['name' => $values[0], 'nickname' => $values[1]]`…?!

Comment: i don't see how this code can work

Comment: That is the part I do not know how to implement. @executable

Comment: My code is just an example, it does not work. @jabepa

Comment: `var_export(array_combine(['name', 'nickname'], $values));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this

```php
<?php

$values = ["Phillip", "Phil"];

function set(array $values): array
{
        return [ "name" => $values[0], "nickname" => $values[1] ];
}

var_dump(set($values));
```

Result

```bash
array(2) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(7) "Phillip"
  ["nickname"]=>
  string(4) "Phil"
}
```